# How to deal with multiple decimal when parsing XML with XSLT?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I work in Retail side where we have **MaxLineStatus** that implies the current status of the order placed by customer.
As a part of this process, I have a XML that needs to be passed to XSLT for transformation.
My XSLT has a check of MaxLineStatus < 3700.7777 and the value of MaxLineStatus is being passed as 3200.200.100 in the input xml.
In ideal scenario, **3200.200.100** is less than **3700.7777** and in return it should fulfill the criteria and populate the orderLine Node.

Whenever i am passing 3200.200 in place of 3200.200.100 in xml, i am getting the desired output.
I even tried storing the xslt value in some variable and then comparing the value, but still it is not working.

I am comparing the value in below piece of code:

```
<xsl:attribute name="OrderLineCount"><xsl:value-of select="count(./OrderLine[(@MaxLineStatus &lt; 3700.7777) and (@MaxLineStatus!='3200.150') and (@MaxLineStatus!='1400')])" /></xsl:attribute>
```

**Thank you** for the help and sorry for posting the xml and xslt in this manner. I was facing some issue indenting the same. Kindly excuse.

**XML:**

```
<OrderRelease APIName="sendReleaseModificationUpdateToILS" CarrierServiceCode="" DeliveryMethod="DEL" DocumentType="0003" EnterpriseCode="RETAIL" MFLocationId="70" NotificationType=" " OrderDate="20190410T06:49:07" OrderHeaderKey="2019041006490764562203" OrderLineCount="1" PriorityCode="" PriorityNumber="0" ProNumber="" ReleaseNo="1" RewardZoneIndicator="N" SCAC="" SalesOrderNo="1119100622586" ShipNode="BBY_9034" ShippingType="" WorkOrderKey="2019041006493464562225"><Shipnode Localecode="en_US_CST" NodeType="DDC" ReceiptProcessingTime="60.00" ShipNode="BBY_9034"><Extn FulfilmentDateBufferTime="0" LocationID="9034" MFLocationId="70" MobileSAS="N" /></Shipnode><Order CarrierServiceCode="" CustomerEMailID="RACHAKONDA.SATYASRINIVAS@BESTBUY.COM" DocumentType="0001" DraftOrderFlag="N" EnterpriseCode="RETAIL" MaxOrderStatus="3200.200.100" MinOrderStatus="1100.100" NotificationType=" " OrderDate="20190410T06:49:07" OrderHeaderKey="2019041006490764562203" OrderNo="1119100622586" OrderPurpose="" PriorityCode="" PriorityNumber="0" ReturnOrderHeaderKeyForExchange=" " SCAC="" SellerOrganizationCode="BBY_281" ShipNode=" " Status="Partially Awaiting Pickup Date" isHistory="N" /><OrderLine CarrierServiceCode="" ConditionVariable1="" ConditionVariable2="" DeliveryMethod="DEL" DependentOnLineKey=" " DerivedFromOrderHeaderKey="2018012921180556404483" DerivedFromOrderLineKey="2018012921180556404485" FulfillmentType="DELIVERY" HasDerivedChild="" LineType="RETURN" MaxLineStatus="3200.200.100" MaxLineStatusDesc="Awaiting Pickup Date" MinLineStatus="3200.200.100" MinLineStatusDesc="Awaiting Pickup Date" OpenQty="1" OrderLineKey="2019041006490764562204" OrderedQty="1" PrimeLineNo="1" ProcureFromNode="" PromisedApptEndDate="20190413T19:00:00" PromisedApptStartDate="20190413T07:00:00" SCAC="" ShipNode="BBY_9034" ShipToKey=" " Status="Awaiting Pickup Date" SubLineNo="1"><Extn ExpectedShipDate="20190410T00:00:00" StreetDate="19000101T00:00:00"><EOMSOrderLineList><EOMSOrderLine ExpectedApptEndDate="20190413T19:00:00" ExpectedApptStartDate="20190413T07:00:00" HingeSettings="" LineShipNodeWMS="WMS" OrderLineKey="2019041006490764562204" SellingStoreId="281" /></EOMSOrderLineList></Extn><Item CustomerItem="3519796" CustomerItemDesc="NINTENDO DS UNIVERSAL GAME SELECTOR CASE" ItemID="1640461" ManufacturerItem="52LB5D" ProductClass="" ProductLine="9.99.224" UnitOfMeasure="EACH" /><Notes NumberOfNotes="0" /><ParentOrderLineRelationships /></OrderLine></OrderRelease>
```

---

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" /><xsl:template match="/OrderRelease"><xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*" /><xsl:attribute name="MFLocationId"><xsl:value-of select="./Shipnode/Extn/@MFLocationId" /></xsl:attribute><Extn><xsl:attribute name="ReleaseSeqNo"><xsl:value-of select="./Extn/@ReleaseSeqNo" /></xsl:attribute></Extn><xsl:attribute name="OrderLineCount"><xsl:value-of select="count(./OrderLine[(@MaxLineStatus &lt; 3700.7777) and (@MaxLineStatus!='3200.150') and (@MaxLineStatus!='1400')])" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:for-each select="./OrderLine[(@MaxLineStatus &lt; 3700.7777) and (@MaxLineStatus!='3200.150') and (@MaxLineStatus!='1400')]"><OrderLine><xsl:copy-of select="./@*" /><xsl:copy-of select="./OrderLineInvAttRequest" /><Item><xsl:copy-of select="./Item/@*" /><Extn><xsl:attribute name="BrandItemID"><xsl:value-of select="./Item/@CustomerItem" /></xsl:attribute></Extn></Item><Notes><xsl:copy-of select="./Notes/*" /></Notes><ParentOrderLineRelationships><xsl:copy-of select="./ParentOrderLineRelationships/*" /></ParentOrderLineRelationships><Extn><xsl:copy-of select="./Extn/*" /></Extn></OrderLine></xsl:for-each><Notes><xsl:for-each select="./Notes/Note"><xsl:copy-of select="current()" /></xsl:for-each></Notes><Order><xsl:attribute name="OrderPurpose"><xsl:value-of select="./Order/@OrderPurpose" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="ReturnOrderHeaderKeyForExchange"><xsl:value-of select="./Order/@ReturnOrderHeaderKeyForExchange" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="CustomerEMailID"><xsl:value-of select="./Order/@CustomerEMailID" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="SellerOrganizationCode"><xsl:value-of select="./Order/@SellerOrganizationCode" /></xsl:attribute><Extn><xsl:attribute name="BillingPhoneNo"><xsl:value-of select="./Order/Extn/@BillingPhoneNo" /></xsl:attribute></Extn></Order><xsl:copy-of select="./PersonInfoShipTo" /></xsl:copy></xsl:template>
```

**Actual Result:**

```
<OrderRelease APIName="sendReleaseModificationUpdateToILS" CarrierServiceCode="" DeliveryMethod="DEL" DocumentType="0003" EnterpriseCode="RETAIL" MFLocationId="70" NotificationType=" " OrderDate="20190410T06:49:07" OrderHeaderKey="2019041006490764562203" OrderLineCount="1" PriorityCode="" PriorityNumber="0" ProNumber="" ReleaseNo="1" RewardZoneIndicator="N" SCAC="" SalesOrderNo="1119100622586" ShipNode="BBY_9034" ShippingType="" WorkOrderKey="2019041006493464562225"><Extn ReleaseSeqNo="" /><Notes></Notes><Order OrderPurpose="" ReturnOrderHeaderKeyForExchange=" " CustomerEMailID="RACHAKONDA.SATYASRINIVAS@BESTBUY.COM" SellerOrganizationCode="BBY_281"><Extn BillingPhoneNo="" /></Order></OrderRelease>
```

---

**Expected Result:**

```
<OrderRelease APIName="sendReleaseModificationUpdateToILS" CarrierServiceCode="" DeliveryMethod="DEL" DocumentType="0003" EnterpriseCode="RETAIL" MFLocationId="70" NotificationType=" " OrderDate="20190410T06:49:07" OrderHeaderKey="2019041006490764562203" OrderLineCount="1" PriorityCode="" PriorityNumber="0" ProNumber="" ReleaseNo="1" RewardZoneIndicator="N" SCAC="" SalesOrderNo="1119100622586" ShipNode="BBY_9034" ShippingType="" WorkOrderKey="2019041006493464562225"><Extn ReleaseSeqNo="" /><OrderLine CarrierServiceCode="" ConditionVariable1="" ConditionVariable2="" DeliveryMethod="DEL" DependentOnLineKey=" " DerivedFromOrderHeaderKey="2018012921180556404483" DerivedFromOrderLineKey="2018012921180556404485" FulfillmentType="DELIVERY" HasDerivedChild="" LineType="RETURN" MaxLineStatus="3200.200.100" MaxLineStatusDesc="Awaiting Pickup Date" MinLineStatus="3200.200.100" MinLineStatusDesc="Awaiting Pickup Date" OpenQty="1" OrderLineKey="2019041006490764562204" OrderedQty="1" PrimeLineNo="1" ProcureFromNode="" PromisedApptEndDate="20190413T19:00:00" PromisedApptStartDate="20190413T07:00:00" SCAC="" ShipNode="BBY_9034" ShipToKey=" " Status="Awaiting Pickup Date" SubLineNo="1"><Item CustomerItem="3519796" CustomerItemDesc="NINTENDO DS UNIVERSAL GAME SELECTOR CASE" ItemID="1640461" ManufacturerItem="52LB5D" ProductClass="" ProductLine="9.99.224" UnitOfMeasure="EACH"><Extn BrandItemID="3519796" /></Item><Notes></Notes><ParentOrderLineRelationships></ParentOrderLineRelationships><Extn><EOMSOrderLineList><EOMSOrderLine ExpectedApptEndDate="20190413T19:00:00" ExpectedApptStartDate="20190413T07:00:00" HingeSettings="" LineShipNodeWMS="WMS" OrderLineKey="2019041006490764562204" SellingStoreId="281" /></EOMSOrderLineList></Extn></OrderLine><Notes></Notes><Order OrderPurpose="" ReturnOrderHeaderKeyForExchange=" " CustomerEMailID="RACHAKONDA.SATYASRINIVAS@BESTBUY.COM" SellerOrganizationCode="BBY_281"><Extn BillingPhoneNo="" /></Order></OrderRelease>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "multiple decimal". The string "3200.200.100" is not a number. If you want to compare it to a number, you must convert it to a number first. Please explain the **logic** by which this should be done.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The xml will have the value as String only. I am looking for an approach by which this can be achieved. I need to compare the XSLT status(3700.7777) with the XML one. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: It would help if you could format your XML for human legibility.

Comment: No, because I do not understand the logic by which "3200.200.100" is less than 3700.7777. Why is it less? You only give us one example and an arbitrary result. Give us the rule instead.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 1.0 the only way to compare strings for `<` and `>` relationships is by sorting; the `<` and `>` operators always convert to numbers (and if the value can't be converted to a number, it is treated as NaN).

Ideally, move forward to a more recent XSLT version (1.0 is getting VERY old).

If you can't do that, then it's going to be a convoluted work-around. Three possible approaches:

(a) find some way of converting these "dotted decimal" values into numbers that sort correctly. (e.g. pad each component to a standard number of digits, then strip the dots).

(b) sort the values, allocate sequence numbers, and test whether a value satisfies the relevant condition by looking at the sequence numbers.

(c) call out to an extension function in an external language such as Java to do the comparison.